# How do I add text to each text value in a Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript

I am receiving in my App an Array of text from a backend I have no control over

Array

```
this.Array = ["/tms/open-attachment/121", "/tms/open-attachment/122"]
```

I am trying to add "some text added here" to the beginning

```
this.Array =  ["some text added here/tms/open-attachment/121", "some text added here/tms/open-attachment/122"]
```

Using

```
for (let m = 0; m <this.Array.length; m++) { 

}
```

I have been able to add to the end of the text but not the front.

Is there an easy way to add some custom text to the beginning of the string?

Comment: `Array` is not a reseved word in JS ?

Comment: Why can you add to the end but not the beginning? It's just `new + a` versus `a + new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.map` and concatenate what you need:

```js
const arr = ["/tms/open-attachment/121", "/tms/open-attachment/122"];
const result = arr.map(str => 'some text added here' + str);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a traditional for loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    array[i] = "some text" + array[i];
}
```

Or, as said CertainPerformance, you can use a [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map):

```js
array = array.map(str => "some text" + str)
```